# inview.jsでスクロールした際に文字を浮かび上がらせたい

Tags: javascript, html, css

#### 実現したいこと

こちらのサイトを参考にスクロールしたときに文字を浮かび上がらせたいです。
「1.【サンプル】フェードイン（ふわっと）」をまねしたいです。

現状は表示させたい文字が現れません。

[【jQuery】スクロールして表示領域に入ったら要素をアニメーション表示させる『inview.js』の実装サンプル集](https://125naroom.com/web/3532)

#### 解説をいただきたい部分

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

①なぜ最初に$(なのか

②eventはここでのスクロール操作なのか

③isInviewの役割

④stop()の意味

よろしくお願いいたします。

```js
$(function() {
  $('.inview').on('inview', function (event, isInview) {
    if(isInview) {
      $(this).stop().addClass('is-show');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
* {
    background-attachment: fixed;
}


/* aboutmeの余白をうまいことしたい */


.navbar {}


header {
    padding: 300px 0;
    background-image: url(images/top.jpg);
    height: 100px;
}

.fadeIn {
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 2s;

}

.fadeIn.is-show {
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Iori's Website</title>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>


  <!-- slick ‍headとbody終わりの直前-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>


  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3715e2b643.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ress/dist/ress.min.css"> -->
  
</head>




<body class="text-center">


  <!-- Nav Bar -->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">yoriss67</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
      aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">

      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <!-- Title -->


  <header id="header">
    <div>
      <h1 class="fadeIn">Thank you for visiting.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <p class="fadeIn" data-test-daa="This is a test">I'm Iori.</p>
    </div>
    </style>


  </header>

  <hr>

  <div class="aboutme">
    <h2>About Me</h2>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="imgprofile" src="images/8fdb71d0-e360-4b74-9761-7795784871bd-0-modified.png" alt="my-profile"
          width="200px" height="200px">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>I'm a sophomore student at a university in Japan. My major is English and Social Science.
          <br><br>I have started studying programming out of mainly curiosity and a bit of hope to make use of it for my
          future career.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <a href="https://www.notion.so/396eca31a8f44b5c989ac4b8efa302f0?v=c3d6906ee5654da9a5534cfa7b0b79bc&p=d67a03c53bd949b0902f76774734cf57&pm=s" target="_blank">Here's my Notion.</a> -->

  </div>


  <hr>


  <div class="mywebdevelopmentpath">
    <h2>My Web Development Path</h2>


    <!-- Web Dev Blog-->
    <button data-modal-id="modal-1">Open Modal 1</button>
    <button data-modal-id="modal-2">Open Modal 2</button>

    <div id="modal-1">Modal 1</div>
    <div id="modal-2">Modal 2</div>




  </div>


  <hr>


  <div class="whatilike">
    <h2>What I like</h2>

    <div class="slider">
      <div><img src="images/surfers.jpg" alt="surfers" /></div>
      <div><img src="images/circle.jpg" alt="circle" /></div>
      <div><img src="images/kelia.jpg" alt="kelia" /></div>
      <div><img src="images/sunset.jpg" alt="sunset" /></div>
      <div><img src="images/surfboy.jpg" alt="surfboy" /></div>
      <div><img src="images/yogurt.jpg" alt="yogurt" /></div>
      <div><img src="images/palmtree.jpg" alt="palmtree" /></div>
      <div><img src="images/yoga.jpg" alt="yoga" /></div>

    </div>


  </div>

  <hr>

  <h2>Works</h2>
  <div class="works">
    
<ul>
    <li id="Travel Blog">
      <div>
      <a href="https://yoriss67.github.io/Travel-Blog/" target="_blank">
        <img src="./images/images06.jpg" alt="images06">
        <h5>Travel Blog</h5>
      </a>
  
    </div>
    <div>

    <small> Sep 2022 </small>
    <p>初めての模写です。</p>

    </div>

    </li>


    <li id="Travel Blog">
      <a href="https://yoriss67.github.io/Travel-Blog/" target="_blank">
        <img src="./images/images06.jpg" alt="images06">
        <h5>Travel Blog</h5>
      </a>
      <span> Sep 2022 </span>
    </li>

    <li id="Travel Blog">
      <a href="https://yoriss67.github.io/Travel-Blog/" target="_blank">
        <img src="./images/images06.jpg" alt="images06">
        <h5>Travel Blog</h5>
      </a>
      <span> Sep 2022 </span>
    </li>

  </ul>




  </div>



<h2>Contact</h2>

<div class="contact">
<div class="github">
  <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
  <a href="https://github.com/yoriss67">yoriss67</a>
</div>

<div class="twitter">
  <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/iori73wsy">Iori67</a>
</div>

<div class="instagram">
  <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram">  </i>

    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ioriiii_13/">ioriii_13</a>
</div>

</div>












<!-- inview CDN -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inview/1.0.0/jquery.inview.min.js"></script>


<!-- inview download -->

<script src="./jquery.inview.min.js"></script>

  <!-- slick -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js">
  </script>




  <script src="index.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 回答を書いてみましたが、やはり質問項目が多すぎると感じました。できるだけ一問一答形式の読み易い Q&A になるように心掛けていただけると、回答も付きやすいかと思います。ソースコードも[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)を参考に、再現可能な最小限のコードを作成するのが解決への早道です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### なぜ最初に `$(` なのか

jQuery というライブラリを使用しているので、`$` は `jQuery` を指します。

> `jQuery(callback)`
>
> DOM Documentのロードが終わった際に、バインドしておいた関数が実行されるようになる。
> この関数は `$(document).ready()` と全く同様に動作する。
> —— [jQuery(callback)](http://semooh.jp/jquery/api/core/jQuery/callback/)

例えば HTML の最後に JavaScript を書くなら、必要ありません。

#### `event` はここでのスクロール操作なのか

jQuery のプラグインである [inview](https://github.com/zuk/jquery.inview) を使用しているので、それによって追加された `inview` イベントです。スクロール操作により発生するという意味では、スクロール操作であると言えます。

#### `isInview` の役割

> The event will only fire when the element comes in to view of the viewport, and out of view.
> ...
> The variable after the event argument indicates the visible state in the viewport.
> —— [Usage](https://github.com/zuk/jquery.inview#usage)

イベントはターゲットの要素が可視領域に入った時と出た時の両方で発生します。どちらなのか区別するのが2番目の引数 (質問のコードでは `isInview` として利用) です。

#### `stop()` の意味

> 指定した要素集合から、現在動作中のアニメーション処理を全て中止します。
> —— [`stop()`](http://semooh.jp/jquery/api/effects/stop/_/)

他でアニメーションさせていないなら、必要ないと思います。

#### 「現状は表示させたい文字が現れません」

現在の JavaScript では `$('.inview').on('inview'`  としていますね。対象の要素を `inview` というクラスで探しています。しかし、HTML には `inview` クラスが指定されていません。HTML で `class="inview fadeIn"` のように `inview` クラスを追加する必要があります。

もしくは、JavaScript 側を `$('.fadeIn').on('inview'`  のようにして `fadeIn` クラスで探すようにしてもよいでしょう。

（その他にも、重複した JavaScript の読み込みや、 `color: #fff;` など気になる点はあります）

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘いただいたとおりHTMLにinviewクラスを指定すると表示されました。アドバイス誠に感謝いたします。